# How do I find $\lim_{n\to 0}(s_{n+1}-s_n)$?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\{s_n\}_{n\geq 0}\subset [0,1]$ be a sequence such that $2s_n\leq s_{n-1}+s_{n+1}$ for all $n\geq 1$. Then

(a) $\lim \limits _{n\to 0}(s_{n+1}-s_n)$ does not exist.

(b) $\lim \limits _{n\to 0}(s_{n+1}-s_n)=0$.

(c) $\lim \limits _{n\to 0}(s_{n+1}-s_n)=1$.

(d) $\lim \limits _{n\to 0}(s_{n+1}-s_n)=\dfrac{1}{2}$.

If we take $s_n=\dfrac{1}{n+1}$ does not discard all of the options? Because, $$\lim_{n\to 0}(s_{n+1}-s_n)=-\frac{1}{2}$$

Am I correct or am I doing some stupid mistake? And if I am correct is it true in general that $\lim \limits_{n\to 0}(s_{n+1}-s_n)=-\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: as $n\to\infty$, perhaps?

Comment: no!! I got the question as $n\to 0$

Comment: if $n\to \infty$ I am able to answer, the answer would be option (b)

Comment: $n\to 0$ amounts to computing $s_1-s_0$, which obviously is a well defined quantity.

Comment: ahh! it was very trivial!!

Comment: Im confused.. you don’t know the value of $s_0$, how can you determine the solution?

Comment: That seems like a very strange way of asking whether $2s_{n} \leqslant s_{n-1}+s_{n+1}$ restricts enough the choice of possible sequences.